# Strange characters displaying a content

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a strange issue when storing a block of text in DB and later displaying it in a web browser.

Let's suppose the following original text:

> Last month, while my colleagues from the 3DPrint.com team were soaking up the sun at [RAPID 2016](https://3dprint.com/135642/rapid-2016-in-photos/), back at home [we reported on the new methodologies](https://3dprint.com/134894/type-a-machines-methods/) for generating internal structures that were unveiled by [Type A Machines](https://www.typeamachines.com/). Their Cura Type A software, [which is currently available for download as a public beta release](https://www.typeamachines.com/downloads), has been enhanced with new features that provides increased access and efficiency for generating internal geometries and infills within your 3D prints. Type A Machines refers to the inner-workings of a 3D object as ‘internal structure’ rather than infill, and the change in name lends credence to the fact that these features are a true breakthrough in 3D printing software.

and this is what I display in my website:

> Last month, while my colleagues from the 3DPrint.com team wereÃÂ soaking up the sun at RAPID 2016, back at homeÃÂ we reported on the new methodologies for generating internal structures that were unveiled by Type A Machines. Their Cura Type A software, which is currently available for download as a public beta release, has been enhanced with new features that provides increased access and efficiency for generating internal geometries and infills within your 3D prints. Type A Machines refers to the inner-workings of a 3D object as Ã¢ÂÂinternal structureÃ¢ÂÂ rather than infill, and the change in name lends credence to the fact that these features are a true breakthrough in 3D printing software.

Well, in my script PHP, once I get the content via **file_get_content** function, I use **utf8_encode** before send it to the DB.

Well, What should I do to avoiding showing the strange characters?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to serialize them before sending to database and unserialize before displaying data?